# Highchart - The expected type comes from property 'dashStyle' which is declared here on type 'XAxisPlotLinesOptions'

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have added the below code in the `xAxis` in the highchart.

```
plotLines: [
    {
      color: 'grey',
      width: 2,
      dashStyle: 'line'
    }
],
```

I am getting the below chart, previously I used the `dashStyle` in other work, here only I am getting the below issue.

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
      Overload 1 of 2, '(options: Options, callback?: ChartCallbackFunction): Chart', gave the following error.
        Type '"trgt-testcntrl"' has no properties in common with type 'Options'.
      Overload 2 of 2, '(renderTo: string | HTMLElement, options: Options, callback?: ChartCallbackFunction): Chart', gave the following error.
        Type '"line"' is not assignable to type 'DashStyleValue'.

node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.d.ts:115249:5
        115249     dashStyle?: DashStyleValue;
                   ~~~~~~~~~
        The expected type comes from property 'dashStyle' which is declared here on type 'XAxisPlotLinesOptions'
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such possible dash style as `line`.
In the API reference, you might find the available one.

**API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.DashStyleValue 

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-dztepl**

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but the previous projects I used. May be older version had a line.